How to sanitise and validate JSON input
I currently have a import/export feature of the user's localData.
I'm new with using JSON, and I need help with sanitizing and validation of the data to make this feature safe.
Local data contains multiple Tab elements, defined as follows:
type Product = {
  imageURL: string;
  productBrand: string;
  productCategory: number;
  productId: number;
  productName: string;
  productPrice: number;
  shopImageURL: string;
  shopName: string;
  shopURL: string;
};

type Tab = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  term: string;
  products: Product[];
  seenItems: Set<number>;
  newItems: Product[];
};

This is how the import and export are written
const handleImportData = (data: string) => {

    try {
      const parsedData = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(data));



      const importedTabs: Tab[] = parsedData.map((tab: any) => ({
        ...tab,
        seenItems: new Set(tab.seenItems),
      }));

      setTabs(importedTabs);
      if (importedTabs.length > 0) {
        setActiveTabId(importedTabs[0].id);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error parsing imported tabs data:", err);
      // Handle error state or show error message
    }
  };

const handleExportData = () => {
    const tabsData = tabs.map((tab) => ({
      ...tab,
      seenItems: Array.from(tab.seenItems),
    }));

    const dataStr = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(tabsData));
    return dataStr;
  };

  const handleResetData = () => {
    setTabs([]);
    setActiveTabId(null);
  };




I am using React/NEXT.js with typescript.
Any help would be appreciated.
I've tried making my own Ajv schema, which didn't work:
const tabSchema: JSONSchemaType<Tab> = {
    type: "object",
    definitions: {
      product: {
        type: "object",
        properties: {
          productId: { type: "number" },
          productBrand: { type: "string" },
          productCategory: { type: "number" },
          productName: { type: "string" },
          productPrice: { type: "number" },
          imageURL: { type: "string" },
          shopName: { type: "string" },
          shopURL: { type: "string" },
          shopImageURL: { type: "string" },
        },
        required: [
          "productId",
          "productBrand",
          "productCategory",
          "productName",
          "productPrice",
          "imageURL",
          "shopName",
          "shopURL",
          "shopImageURL",
        ],
      },
    },
    properties: {
      id: { type: "number" },
      name: { type: "string" },
      term: { type: "string" },
      products: { type: "array", items: { $ref: "#/definitions/product" } },
      seenItems: { type: "array", items: { type: "number" } },
      newItems: { type: "array", items: { $ref: "#/definitions/product" } },
    },
    required: ["id", "name", "term", "products", "seenItems", "newItems"],
  };

